# Enable Edge Scrolling - Ubuntu 14

Tags: touchpad, vmware, acer

I am running Ubuntu 14, and in my mouse and touchpad options, there is no setting for edge scrolling. There are only settings for "double click" and "mouse speed," nothing for scrolling.

I found a forum answer to install "Unity Tweak Tool" for more options. I installed it and switched my scroll options **in the Tweak Tool** to "enable edge scrolling", but it still isn't working.

Is it maybe that my computer's trackpad simply doesn't support that feature?

I am running Ubuntu 14 through VMware, with Windows 8 as the host computer, on an Acer Aspire E5. 2-finger scroll works in both Windows and the Linux VM, but I just like edge scrolling much better and was hoping for a way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Very simple solution to that --- 
the edge scrolling function is not the 'default' function in ubuntu 14.04

Go to settings, then click on 'mouse and touchpad' then just uncheck the 'two finger scrolling' option. 
There you go, no restart, no hassle

Comment: This still works as in version 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

just paste this in your terminal and both scrolls would start working

```
synclient VertEdgeScroll=1
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have both two-finger and edge scrollings (simultaneously) enabled. If you disable two-finger scroll in Mouse and Touchpad Settings edge scrolling will be enabled automatically.

I guess working two-finger scrolling shows your touchpad is supported and edge scrolling should work either.